# Bootstrap | JQuery: How to enable "Required" validation on fields during Form Submit Click?

Tags: jquery, validation, jsp, bootstrap-4, jquery-ajax

Following is JS Code:

```
$('#createCust').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            documentCommon.ajax({
                dataType : 'text',
                url : "/createcustomer",
                data : $("body form:first").serialize(),
                success : function(data) {
                    $(".dialogTitle").html("");
                    $(".dialogTitle").html("Add Customer");
                    $(".actualData").html("");
                    $(".actualData").html(data);
                    $('#modalViewDialog').modal('show');
                }
            });
        });
```

Following is button:

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="customerForm"
        class="form-signin" action="/createcustomer">
  <form:input type="text" path="customerName" class="form-control"
                                placeholder="Customer Name" required="required"></form:input>
  <button type="submit" id="createCust" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
```

When i remove JS code then it works fine but i want ajax call so i could not rely on whole page submit. Is there any way to enabled all required field check on JS call too?

Comment: What is it?? `documentCommon` Try changing `$.ajax`

Comment: I don't see anything in the question about the jQuery Validate plugin.  Removed tag.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way to achieve above is to check if the inputs are *not empty* using `!= ""` and depending on this make your ajax call or show error .

Here is an example if you know the name of inputs and want to check each input manually.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('#createCust').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //check if customer not empty
  if ($("input[name='customerName']").val() != "") {
    console.log("go to backend")
    /*your ajax call*/

  } else {
    //do something to show error
    console.log("please fill above")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" modelAttribute="customerForm" class="form-signin" action="/createcustomer">
  <input type="text" path="customerName" name="customerName" class="form-control" placeholder="Customer Name">
  <button type="submit" id="createCust" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
</form>
```

If you have large form then you can just loop through all inputs inside form and check if `val()` is not empty depending on this call your ajax or show errors .Modify below code according to your requirements.

***Demo code*** :

```js
$('#createCust').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var count =0
  var validate_ = true;
  var inputs_=$(".form-signin > input").length;
  //loop through form inputs
  $(".form-signin > input").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
    count++;
      validate_ = true; //not null
    } else {
    count--;
      validate_ = false;
    }
  })
  console.log(inputs_ == count)
  //check validate status
  if (validate_ && inputs_ == count) {
    console.log("go to backend")
    /*your ajax call*/

  } else {
    //do something to show error
    console.log("please fill above")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" modelAttribute="customerForm" class="form-signin" action="/createcustomer">
  <input type="text" path="customerName" name="customerName" class="form-control" placeholder="Customer Name"><br/>
  <input type="text" path="customerName" name="soemthing" class="form-control" placeholder="somthing"><br/>
  <input type="text" path="customerName" name="somthing" class="form-control" placeholder="somthing"><br/>
  <button type="submit" id="createCust" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button><br/>
</form>
```